# Remove tables intersection

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, except, minus

Given two columns, t1 with distinct values, but a superset of t2, how is it possible to operate over t1 to subtract the elements of t2 of t1? I utilize MySQL 5.7

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
   id_ INTEGER  NOT NULL,
   value1 INT NOT NULL
INSERT INTO t1 (id_, value1) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6),
(7),
(8)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
   id_ INTEGER  NOT NULL,
   value1 INT NOT NULL
INSERT INTO t2 (id_, value2) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4)
```

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto: The `EXCEPT` or `MINUS` operation would seem perfect for this, as suggested by the tags just edited in. But since MySQL 5.7 supports neither, an anti-join is probably the only option for you, and what you did was one of the ways of implementing an anti-join. (The other two I know of involve `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN`, but the `LEFT JOIN` + `WHERE IS NULL` option that you used is used most often in MySQL.) So it looks like you managed this on your own, well done.

Comment: Ok, I am satisfied with the answer. Thank you.